# update panel updates page completely but i need to update just itself

Tags: asp.net

i'm so angry i put an update panel with a timer and label :

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" ID="upTimer">
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" ></asp:Timer>

</ContentTemplate>
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Lab1"></asp:Label>
            <br/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbTime"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in codebehind i wrote to set DateTime.Now to label in "PageLoad" it shouldnt update every second but it is updateing :((

Code Behind :

```
public DateTime endTime;
    public TimeSpan timespann;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        lbTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //timespann = endTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        //DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        //Response.Write(endTime.Subtract(now).TotalSeconds.ToString());
        //Lab1.Text = timespann.ToString();
        //lbTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `Tick` event fires it causes a `PostBack` event which is causing the page to reload; hence the label updating every second.

To stop it from updating you need to wrap the code in the `Page_Load` event with `!IsPostBack` e.g.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     endTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
     lbTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```